# Application of Implicit Function theorem for this problem

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Let $f: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ be of class $C^1$; write $f$ in the form $f(x,y_1,y_2)$. Assume that $f(3,-1,2) = \mathbf{0}$ and
>   $$ Df(3,-1,2) = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 1 \\ 1 & -1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}.$$
>
> (a) Show that there is a function $g: B \to \mathbb{R}^2$ of class $C^1$ defined on an open set $B$ in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x,g_1(x),g_2(x)) = \mathbf{0}$ for $x \in B$ and $g(3) = (-1,2)$.
>
> (b) Find $Dg(3)$.

I have done a. I have no idea how to solve b. Please help.

Comment: My earlier comment was a little misleading. It is a direct application of the implicit function theorem, but I had accidentally written $x$ instead of $y$. I have atoned for my sin below :-).

Answer (score 1):

Write $f$ (which is  $C^1$) as $f:\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$.

Note that ${ \partial f(3,(-1,2)^T) \over \partial y}$ is invertible, and
 $f(3,(-1,2)^T)=0$. The implicit function theorem gives the existence of
a $C^1$ function $g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2$ such that
$f(x,g(x)) = 0$ for $x$ in a neighbourhood of $3$ and $g(3) = (-1,2)^T$.

The implicit function theorem also gives a formula for the derivative of $g$
as ${ \partial g(3) \over \partial x} = - { \partial f(3,(-1,2)^T) \over \partial y}^{-1} { \partial f(3,(-1,2)^T) \over \partial x} = (0,-1)^T
$.

Comment: Why are you writing $(-1,2)^T$?  I read the question from the munkres text and am trying to understand your notation

Comment: I was being pedantic. (i) Instead of $f(x,y_1,y_2)$ I use $f(x,y)$, where $y \in \mathbb{R}^2$. (ii) For elements of $\mathbb{R}^2$ I write a column vector, hence the $^T$. I had a minor error as well, $g$ is a function of $\mathbb{R}$.